# How to Increase ECS FARGATE Container Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have ECS FARGATE Cluster running with few fargate containers (NOT ECS INSTANCE).

I would like to increase Fargate container storage volume.

I know Default is 10GB, Is it possible to increase it more then 15GB?

Or

Is there any other alternative way to store files in one place and access by Fargate Container?

Comment: Fargate storage is ephemeral. One of the options is that you can store your files in S3.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can extend volume size in Fargate container, instead of that, you can use the s3 bucket as a storage option.